# R get actual value inside matrix after make it absolute

Tags: r, matrix

Does anyone could help me with this? Because I'm quite new to R.
Let say, I have a matrix with size 2x6 with values as follow:

```
da <- matrix(c(0.5,-0.5,1,-0.25,1.75,0.25,0.75,1.75,0.5,1.5,-0.75,0.25),ncol=6,nrow=2)
```

and I want R to give me the absolute minimum value for each column with this command:

```
abs.da <- apply(abs(da),2,min)
abs.da
# [1] 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.75 0.50 0.25
```

and after that I want R to give me the real values of the minimum absolute whether it is a negative or positive number. I want the result would be in a vector with values like this:

```
new.da <- c(0.5,-0.25,0.25,0.75,0.5,0.25)
```

I've tried with several command as follow :

```
new.da <- da[abs(da)%in%abs.da]
new.da
# [1]  0.50 -0.50 -0.25  0.25  0.75  0.50 -0.75  0.25
```

which is not what I want because in the first column we have both 0.5 and -0.5 satisfied the condition and I need only one result for each column.

and then I've tried with this command :

```
new.da <- da[match(abs.da,abs(da),nomatch=abs(da),incomparables=which(da[1,]==-da[2,]))]
new.da
# [1]  0.50 -0.25 -0.25  0.75  0.50 -0.25
```

which is still not what I want because -0.25 repeating several times.

Answer (score 0):

```
da <- matrix(c(0.5,-0.5,1,-0.25,1.75,0.25,0.75,1.75,0.5,1.5,-0.75,0.25),ncol=6,nrow=2)
abs.da <- apply( abs( da ), 2, min )
```

You can identify the indices for the values that match your query like this:

```
ix <- apply( abs( da ), 2, function( x ) x%in%min(abs( x ) ) )
```

When there are two values that fit your query, you will still have to decide which one to choose, but the information you need is all there when you do it this way.

E.g. if you wanted to choose the larger of the two (like in your example), you could do:

```
    new.da <- apply( da*ix, 2, function( x ) max( x[ x != 0 ] ) ) 
  > new.da
  [1]  0.50 -0.25  0.25  0.75  0.50  0.25
```

Comment: There is a problem if the matrix contains 0's, So far, all 0's in `da*ix` are disregarded, not only those 0's that come from 0's in `ix`.  To fix it, replace `apply( da*ix, 2, function(x) max( x[ x != 0 ] ) )` by `apply(replace(da,!ix,-Inf),2,max)`. Then it works.

Comment: True. The code I wrote is dismissive of 0 entries in the original matrix, and so `replace( )` is a better solution than just multiplying. `replace( )` also makes it easier to implement your choice rule for where there are multiple matches. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

A long one-liner, but it seems to work:

```
apply(abs(da),2,min) * (2*(apply(replace(da,which(da<0),Inf),2,min) == apply(abs(da),2,min)) - 1)
```

Example 1:

```
> da <- matrix(c(0.5,-0.5,1,-0.25,1.75,0.25,0.75,1.75,0.5,1.5,-0.75,0.25),ncol=6,nrow=2)

> da
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]
[1,]  0.5  1.00 1.75 0.75  0.5 -0.75
[2,] -0.5 -0.25 0.25 1.75  1.5  0.25

> apply(abs(da),2,min) * (2*(apply(replace(da,which(da<0),Inf),2,min) == apply(abs(da),2,min)) - 1)

[1]  0.50 -0.25  0.25  0.75  0.50  0.25
```

Example 2:

```
> set.seed(1)
> da <- matrix(sample(-10:10,5*8,replace=TRUE),5,8)
> 
> da
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   -5    8   -6    0    9   -2    0    4
[2,]   -3    9   -7    5   -6  -10    2    6
[3,]    2    3    4   10    3   -2    0   -8
[4,]    9    3   -2   -3   -8    8   -7    5
[5,]   -6   -9    6    6   -5   -3    7   -2
> apply(abs(da),2,min) * (2*(apply(replace(da,which(da<0),Inf),2,min) == apply(abs(da),2,min)) - 1)

[1]  2  3 -2  0  3 -2  0 -2
>
```

Speed comparison:

```
> da <- matrix(c(0.5,-0.5,1,-0.25,1.75,0.25,0.75,1.75,0.5,1.5,-0.75,0.25),ncol=6,nrow=2)

> da
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]
[1,]  0.5  1.00 1.75 0.75  0.5 -0.75
[2,] -0.5 -0.25 0.25 1.75  1.5  0.25

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:100000 )
+   {
+     ix <- apply( abs( da ), 2, function( x ) x%in%min(abs( x ) ) )
+     DH4wes <- apply( da*ix, 2, f .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  25.85    0.02   26.55 

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:100000 )
+   {
+     mra68 <- apply(abs(da),2,min) * (2*(apply(replace(da,which(da<0),Inf),2,min) == apply(abs(da),2,m .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  17.48    0.00   17.71 

> DH4wes
[1]  0.50 -0.25  0.25  0.75  0.50  0.25

> mra68
[1]  0.50 -0.25  0.25  0.75  0.50  0.25

> #----------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> set.seed(1)

> da <- matrix(sample(-10:10,10*10,replace=TRUE),10,10)

> da
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   -5   -6    9    0    7    0    9   -3   -1    -5
 [2,]   -3   -7   -6    2    3    8   -4    7    4    -9
 [3,]    2    4    3    0    6   -1   -1   -3   -2     3
 [4,]    9   -2   -8   -7    1   -5   -4   -3   -4     8
 [5,]   -6    6   -5    7    1   -9    3    0    5     6
 [6,]    8    0   -2    4    6   -8   -5    8   -6     6
 [7,]    9    5  -10    6  -10   -4    0    8    4    -1
 [8,]    3   10   -2   -8    0    0    6   -2   -8    -2
 [9,]    3   -3    8    5    5    3   -9    6   -5     7
[10,]   -9    6   -3   -2    4   -2    8   10   -7     2

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:10000 )
+   {
+     ix <- apply( abs( da ), 2, function( x ) x%in%min(abs( x ) ) )
+     DH4wes <- apply( da*ix, 2, fu .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  17.96    0.00   18.13 

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:10000 )
+   {
+     mra68 <- apply(abs(da),2,min) * (2*(apply(replace(da,which(da<0),Inf),2,min) == apply(abs(da),2,mi .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
   4.96    0.00    4.97 

> DH4wes
 [1]    2 -Inf   -2 -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf   -1   -1

> mra68
 [1]  2  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>
```

The warnings arise in DH4wes's solution when the minimum is 0:

```
Warning messages:
1: In max(x[x != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(x[x != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```